# Hashtable open addressing handling probing cycles

Tags: hash, hashtable

I have been investigating various collision resolution techniques for hashtables implemented via open addressing. However, all the collision resolution methods I have investigated so far (linear probing, quadratic probing, double hashing) have the pitfall that there exists a probing sequence that produces a cycle whose length is less than the size of the table. This becomes problematic when you're trying to insert an element with the open addressing scheme because there are free buckets to insert an entry but they might not be reachable if they're not part of the cycle.

For example, if we're using linear probing on a table of size 12 with the linear function: H(k, i) = (h(k) + 4*i) mod 12 then a cycle would occur if a particular key hashes to 8 and all the slots 0, 4, and 8 are already filled:

H(k, 0) = 8 + 0  mod 12 = 8

H(k, 1) = 8 + 4  mod 12 = 0

H(k, 2) = 8 + 8  mod 12 = 4

H(k, 3) = 8 + 12 mod 12 = 8

H(k, 4) = 8 + 16 mod 12 = 0

H(k, 5) = 8 + 20 mod 12 = 4

H(k, 6) = 8 + 24 mod 12 = 8

...

Similar cycles can also be found with quadratic and double hashing if the probing sequence is bad, so my question then is how are cycles handled? Or do we always pick hash functions/special table sizes which do not permit cycles which are too short?

Comment: In discrete mathematics (specifically modular arithmetic), those cycles are discouraged because they don't produce every possible result, especially for a hashing function.  When creating the hashing function, I believe co-prime numbers are selected, as that will result in it having no cycles, thus maximizing the size of the set of results.  I know I can't explain this well, but there are great YouTube videos that can!

Comment: I agree with you, choosing a hash function which does not produce every possible result isn't ideal. However, the reason I'm asking the question is to know if it's at all possible to handle the detection of a cycle. This would be beneficial in the event you screw up and select a cyclic hash function; it'd be nice to have a failsafe way to handle such situations.